# Fill in missing dates with 0 (zero) in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a large csv file with millions of rows. The data looks like this. 2 columns (date, score) and million rows. I need the missing dates (for example 1/1/16, 2/1/16, 4/1/16) to have '0' values in the 'score' column and keep my existing 'date' and 'score' intact, all in the same csv. But,I also have multiple (hundreds probably) scores on many dates. So really having trouble to code it. Looked up quite a few examples on stackoverflow but none of them seemed to work yet.

```
date    score
3/1/16  0.6369
5/1/16  -0.2023
6/1/16  0.25
7/1/16  0.0772
9/1/16  -0.4215
12/1/16 0.296
15/1/16 0.25
15/1/16 0.7684
15/1/16 0.8537
...
...
31/12/18 0.5646
```

This is what I have done so far. But all I am getting is an index column filled with 3 years of my 'date' and 'score' columns filled with '0'. I will really appreciate your answers and suggestions. Thank you very much.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

df =pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')

dtr =pd.date_range('01.01.2016', '31.12.2018')
df.index  = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
df =df.reindex(dtr,fill_value = 0)

df.to_csv('missingDateCorrected.csv', encoding ='utf-8', index =True)
```

Note: I know I put index as True that's why the index is appearing but don't know why the 'date' column is not filling. If I put `parse_dates =['date']` in my `pd.read_csv` I get the 'date' column filled with dates from 1970 with the same results as before.

Comment: Problem is there are some duplicated datetimes like `15/1/16`. In output need onkly one `15/1/16` ? If yes, what shoudl be value with `15/1/16` ? mean? first?

Comment: So for first 10 rows in sample data is necessary add `1/1/16`, `2/1/16`, `4/1/16`, `10/1/16` ?

Comment: Sorry. I have not understood the question properly. But to clarify again, for the date that you mentioned I need them to have '0' in the 'score' while keeping my other data unchanged.

Comment: How looks final DataFrame from first  15 rows of sample data?

Comment: It is exactly as I posted. I just copied from the csv file and pasted here. And I don't whether I am allowed to post a sample file. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

(I did it with a smaller timeframe so change the date so that it fits you.)

```
import pandas as pd

x = {"date":["3/1/16","5/1/16","5/1/16"],
    "score":[4,5,6]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(x)
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], format='%d/%m/%y')
df.set_index("date",inplace=True)

dtr =pd.date_range('01.01.2016', '01.10.2016', freq='D')
s = pd.Series(index=dtr)
df = pd.concat([df,s[~s.index.isin(df.index)]]).sort_index()
df = df.drop([0],axis=1).fillna(0)

print(df)
```

## Output

```
            score
2016-01-01    0.0
2016-01-02    0.0
2016-01-03    4.0
2016-01-04    0.0
2016-01-05    5.0
2016-01-05    6.0
2016-01-06    0.0
2016-01-07    0.0
2016-01-08    0.0
2016-01-09    0.0
2016-01-10    0.0
```

## With file

Because you ask in the comment here an example with file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%y')

dtr =pd.date_range('01.01.2016', '01.10.2016', freq='D')
s = pd.Series(index=dtr)
df = pd.concat([df,s[~s.index.isin(df.index)]]).sort_index()
df = df.drop([0],axis=1).fillna(0)

df.to_csv('missingDateCorrected.csv', encoding ='utf-8', index =True)
```

Comment: Do I have to change my csv file data ('date' and 'score') to dict type to do it? Because the data is not in dictionary format. Thank you.

Comment: @Non_linear ofc not. I only created the dataframe that way to not create a file. As long as you have a dataframe the date as your index (in date format) and a column with score it will work. You can then skip until `dtr = ...`

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea . Try resampling with 1 day and fill zeros .
like : nd = df.resample('D').pad()

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'pad'

Answer (score 1):

Not very efficient but will work.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv', index_col=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index, format='%d/%m/%y')

dtr = pd.date_range('01.01.2016', '31.12.2018')

# Create an empty DataFrame from selected date range
empty = pd.DataFrame(index=dtr, columns=['score'])

# Append your CSV file
df = pd.concat([df, empty[~empty.index.isin(df.index)]]).sort_index().fillna(0)

df.to_csv('missingDateCorrected.csv', encoding='utf-8', index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be very close. But it adds an extra date with (NaN) for each existing dates.

Comment: No problem - just updated my answer with fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

Building on a previous incorrect answer, you can simply do:

```
df = df.resample('D').asfreq().fillna(0)
```

First resample to daily, set this as the dataframe frequency and then fill any missing values with zero.